# Spring Boot Multiple Datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm quite new to spring boot and I'd like to create a multiple datasource for my project.
Here is my current case. I have two packages for entity for multiple database. Let's say

```
com.test.entity.db.mysql ; for entities that belong to MySql
com.test.entity.db.h2 ; for entities that belong to H2 Databases
```

So, currently I have two entities class

UserMySql.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usermysql")
public class UserMysql{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;

    public String name;

}
```

UserH2.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userh2")
public class Userh2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;

    public String name;
}
```

I'd like to achieve a configuration where if I create user from UserMySql, it will be saved to MySql Database, and if I create user from Userh2 it will be saved to H2 Databases. So, I also have two DBConfig, let's say MySqlDbConfig and H2DbConfig.

(com.test.model is package where I'll put my Repositories class. It will be defined below)

MySqlDbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages="com.test.model",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManager")
public class MySqlDBConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.test.mysql")
public DataSource mysqlDataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}

@Bean(name="mysqlEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mySqlEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){       
    return builder.dataSource(mysqlDataSource())                
            .packages("com.test.entity.db.mysql")
            .build();
}   

}
```

H2DbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "h2EntityManager")
public class H2DbConfig {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.test.h2")
public DataSource h2DataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name="h2EntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
    return builder.dataSource(h2DataSource())
            .packages("com.test.entity.db.h2")
            .build();
}
}
```

My application.properties file

```
#DataSource settings for mysql
datasource.test.mysql.jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
datasource.test.mysql.username = root
datasource.test.mysql.password = root
datasource.test.mysql.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#DataSource settings for H2
datasource.test.h2.jdbcUrl = jdbc:h2:~/test
datasource.test.h2.username = sa

# DataSource settings: set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1


# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate settings are prefixed with spring.jpa.hibernate.*
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql = true

server.port=8080
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=false
```

And then for crud I have UserMySqlDao and UserH2Dao

UserMySqlDao.java

```
@Transactional 
@Repository
public interface UserMysqlDao extends CrudRepository<UserMysql, Integer>{

    public UserMysql findByName(String name);
}
```

UserH2Dao.java

```
@Transactional
@Repositories
public interface UserH2Dao extends CrudRepository<Userh2, Integer>{

    public Userh2 findByName(String name);
}
```

And for last, I have an UserController as endpoint to access my service

UserController.java

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {


@Autowired
private UserMysqlDao userMysqlDao;

@Autowired
private UserH2Dao userH2Dao;

@RequestMapping("/createM")
@ResponseBody
public String createUserMySql(String name){
    UserMysql user = new UserMysql();
    try{            
        user.name = name;
        userMysqlDao.save(user);
        return "Success creating user with Id: "+user.id;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return "Error creating the user: " + ex.toString();
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/createH")
@ResponseBody
public String createUserH2(String name){
    Userh2 user = new Userh2();
    try{
        user.name = name;
        userH2Dao.save(user);
        return "Success creating user with Id: "+user.id;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return "Error creating the user: " + ex.toString();
    }
}   
}
```

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.test.entity.db")
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Entering spring boot");
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        System.out.print(beanName);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
}

}
```

With this configuration my Spring boot run well, but when I access

```
http://localhost/user/createM?name=myname it writes an exception

Error creating the user: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:   could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

I've googling around and haven't got a solution yet. Any ideas why this exception occurs? And is this the best way to implement multiple datasource to implement my case above? I'm open to full refactor if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Does your code works well with both database run separately?

Comment: yes, if mysql is running alone, it works

Comment: I found this, but it was literally written yesterday http://scattercode.co.uk/2016/01/05/multiple-databases-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

Answer (score 55):

I think you can find it usefull

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

It shows how to define multiple datasources & assign one of them as primary.

Here is a rather full example, also contains distributes transactions - if you need it.

http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/

What you need is to create 2 configuration classes, separate the model/repository packages etc to make the config easy.

Also, in above example, it creates the data sources manually. You can avoid this using the method on spring doc, with @ConfigurationProperties annotation. Here is an example of this:

http://xantorohara.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

Hope these helps.

Comment: Thanks for your links : it helped me solve a similar problem. Though in the `exclude` attribute of the annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, I had to add `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class`, `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class` and `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class`. But it's finally working.

Comment: Sometimes you may need to assign datasource, transactionManager, and SqlSessionFactory as primary all.

Comment: Please @Gokhan, provide the examples that are stated in your referenced pages directly in your answer. Otherwise, this might be considered a "Link only answer". Just think about the given links being moved/deleted.

Answer (score 9):

I faced same issue few days back, I followed the link mentioned below and I could able to overcome the problem

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem (How to connect multiple database using spring and Hibernate) in this way, I hope it will help :)

NOTE: I have added the relevant code, kindly make the dao with the help of impl I used in the below mentioned code.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MultipleDatabaseConnectivityInSpring</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="localPersistenceUnitOne"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>in.india.entities.CustomerDetails</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes />
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shankar?sslmode=require" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="localPersistenceUnitTwo"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>in.india.entities.CompanyDetails</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes />
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shankarTwo?sslmode=require" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**dispatcher-servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    default-autowire="byName"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Configure messageSource -->

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="in.india.*" />
    <bean id="messageResource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        autowire="byName">
        <property name="basename" value="messageResource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryOne"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        autowire="constructor">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="localPersistenceUnitOne" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        autowire="byName">
        <property name="basename" value="messageResource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryTwo"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        autowire="constructor">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="localPersistenceUnitTwo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="manager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryOne" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="manager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryTwo" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="manager1" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="manager2" />

    <!-- declare dependies here -->

    <bean class="in.india.service.dao.impl.CustomerServiceImpl" />
    <bean class="in.india.service.dao.impl.CompanyServiceImpl" />

    <!-- Configure MVC annotations -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
</beans>
```

**java class to persist into one database**

```
package in.india.service.dao.impl;

import in.india.entities.CompanyDetails;
import in.india.service.CompanyService;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactoryTwo")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional("manager2")
    @Override
    public boolean companyService(CompanyDetails companyDetails) {

        boolean flag = false;
        try 
        {
            entityManager.persist(companyDetails);
            flag = true;
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
    }

}
```

**java class to persist in another database**

```
package in.india.service.dao.impl;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import in.india.entities.CustomerDetails;
import in.india.service.CustomerService;

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "localPersistenceUnitOne")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(value = "manager1")
    public boolean customerService(CustomerDetails companyData) {

        boolean flag = false;
        entityManager.persist(companyData);
        return flag;
    }
}
```

**customer.jsp**

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>SpringWithMultipleDatabase's</h1>
    </center>
    <form:form method="GET" action="addCustomer.htm"  modelAttribute="customerBean" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="emailId">Email Id</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="profession">Profession</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="profession" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="address">Address</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**company.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ScheduleJobs</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><h1>SpringWithMultipleDatabase's</h1></center>
 <form:form method="GET" action="addCompany.htm"  modelAttribute="companyBean" >
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companyName">Company Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companyName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companyStrength">Company Strength</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companyStrength" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companyLocation">Company Location</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companyLocation" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><h1>Multiple Database Connectivity In Spring sdfsdsd</h1></center>

<a href='customerRequest.htm'>Click here to go on Customer page</a>
<br>
<a href='companyRequest.htm'>Click here to go on Company page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**success.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ScheduleJobs</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><h1>SpringWithMultipleDatabase</h1></center>
    <b>Successfully Saved</b>
</body>
</html>
```

**CompanyController**

```
package in.india.controller;

import in.india.bean.CompanyBean;
import in.india.entities.CompanyDetails;
import in.india.service.CompanyService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/companyRequest.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addStudent(ModelMap model) {
        CompanyBean companyBean = new CompanyBean();
        model.addAttribute(companyBean);
        return new ModelAndView("company");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCompany.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView companyController(@ModelAttribute("companyBean") CompanyBean companyBean, Model model) {
        CompanyDetails  companyDetails = new CompanyDetails();
        companyDetails.setCompanyLocation(companyBean.getCompanyLocation());
        companyDetails.setCompanyName(companyBean.getCompanyName());
        companyDetails.setCompanyStrength(companyBean.getCompanyStrength());
        companyService.companyService(companyDetails);
        return new ModelAndView("success");

    }
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
package in.india.controller;

import in.india.bean.CustomerBean;
import in.india.entities.CustomerDetails;
import in.india.service.CustomerService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customerRequest.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addStudent(ModelMap model) {
        CustomerBean customerBean = new CustomerBean();
        model.addAttribute(customerBean);
        return new ModelAndView("customer");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView customerController(@ModelAttribute("customerBean") CustomerBean customer, Model model) {
        CustomerDetails customerDetails = new CustomerDetails();
        customerDetails.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
        customerDetails.setAge(customer.getAge());
        customerDetails.setEmailId(customer.getEmailId());
        customerDetails.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
        customerDetails.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
        customerDetails.setProfession(customer.getProfession());
        customerService.customerService(customerDetails);
        return new ModelAndView("success");

    }
}
```

**CompanyDetails Entity**

```
package in.india.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "company_details")
public class CompanyDetails {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "company_details_seq", sequenceName = "company_details_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "company_details_seq")
    @Column(name = "company_details_id")
    private Long companyDetailsId;
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;
    @Column(name = "company_strength")
    private Long companyStrength;
    @Column(name = "company_location")
    private String companyLocation;

    public Long getCompanyDetailsId() {
        return companyDetailsId;
    }

    public void setCompanyDetailsId(Long companyDetailsId) {
        this.companyDetailsId = companyDetailsId;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public Long getCompanyStrength() {
        return companyStrength;
    }

    public void setCompanyStrength(Long companyStrength) {
        this.companyStrength = companyStrength;
    }

    public String getCompanyLocation() {
        return companyLocation;
    }

    public void setCompanyLocation(String companyLocation) {
        this.companyLocation = companyLocation;
    }
}
```

**CustomerDetails Entity**

```
package in.india.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_details")
public class CustomerDetails {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "customer_details_seq", sequenceName = "customer_details_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customer_details_seq")
    @Column(name = "customer_details_id")
    private Long customerDetailsId;
    @Column(name = "first_name ")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name ")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;
    @Column(name = "profession")
    private String profession;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;
    public Long getCustomerDetailsId() {
        return customerDetailsId;
    }

    public void setCustomerDetailsId(Long customerDetailsId) {
        this.customerDetailsId = customerDetailsId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to get away without using bunch of xml config after going the Spring Boot route?

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2018-01-07 with Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE**

If you want to know how to config it, how to use it, and how to control transaction. I may have answers for you.

You can see the runnable example and some explanation in https://www.surasint.com/spring-boot-with-multiple-databases-example/

I copied some code here.

First you have to set application.properties like this

```
#Database
database1.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
database1.datasource.username=root
database1.datasource.password=root
database1.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

database2.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb2
database2.datasource.username=root
database2.datasource.password=root
database2.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Then define them as providers (@Bean) like this:

```
@Bean(name = "datasource1")
@ConfigurationProperties("database1.datasource")
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "datasource2")
@ConfigurationProperties("database2.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource2(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Note that I have @Bean(name="datasource1") and @Bean(name="datasource2"), then you can use it when we need datasource as @Qualifier("datasource1") and @Qualifier("datasource2") , for example

```
@Qualifier("datasource1")
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

If you do care about transaction, you have to define DataSourceTransactionManager for both of them, like this:

```
@Bean(name="tm1")
@Autowired
@Primary
DataSourceTransactionManager tm1(@Qualifier ("datasource1") DataSource datasource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    return txm;
}

@Bean(name="tm2")
@Autowired
DataSourceTransactionManager tm2(@Qualifier ("datasource2") DataSource datasource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    return txm;
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
@Transactional //this will use the first datasource because it is @primary
```

or

```
@Transactional("tm2")
```

This should be enough. See example and detail in the link above.

Comment: URL is not reachable. quick question - Do we need to maintain anything on Entity/Class to show, this entity belongs to datasource1?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple datasource or realizing the separation of reading & writing.
you must have a knowledge of Class `AbstractRoutingDataSource` which support dynamic datasource choose.

Here is my `datasource.yaml` and I figure out how to resolve this case. You can refer to this project [spring-boot + quartz](https://github.com/lvhao/schedule-job). Hope this will help you.

```
dbServer:
  default: localhost:3306
  read: localhost:3306
  write: localhost:3306
datasource:
  default:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    pool-name: default
    continue-on-error: false
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://${dbServer.default}/schedule_job?useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
    username: root
    password: lh1234
    connection-timeout: 30000
    connection-test-query: SELECT 1
    maximum-pool-size: 5
    minimum-idle: 2
    idle-timeout: 600000
    destroy-method: shutdown
    auto-commit: false
  read:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    pool-name: read
    continue-on-error: false
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://${dbServer.read}/schedule_job?useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
    username: root
    password: lh1234
    connection-timeout: 30000
    connection-test-query: SELECT 1
    maximum-pool-size: 5
    minimum-idle: 2
    idle-timeout: 600000
    destroy-method: shutdown
    auto-commit: false
  write:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    pool-name: write
    continue-on-error: false
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://${dbServer.write}/schedule_job?useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
    username: root
    password: lh1234
    connection-timeout: 30000
    connection-test-query: SELECT 1
    maximum-pool-size: 5
    minimum-idle: 2
    idle-timeout: 600000
    destroy-method: shutdown
    auto-commit: false
```

Comment: What he said is correct only. We need to use AbstractRoutingDataSource for achieve this.It will be good if some one can tell whats wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using two datasources you need their own transaction managers.

```
@Configuration
public class MySqlDBConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.test.mysql")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource(){
         return DataSourceBuilder
                 .create()
                 .build();
    }

    @Bean("mysqlTx")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager mysqlTx() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(mysqlDataSource());
    }

    // same for another DS
}
```

And then use it accordingly within @Transaction

```
@Transactional("mysqlTx")
@Repository
public interface UserMysqlDao extends CrudRepository<UserMysql, Integer>{
    public UserMysql findByName(String name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help but it is not complicated as it seems; **almost everything is handled internally by SpringBoot.**

In my case *I want to use Mysql and Mongodb* and the solution was to use `EnableMongoRepositories` and `EnableJpaRepositories` annotations on to my application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMongoRepositories(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MongoRepository))
@EnableJpaRepositories(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MongoRepository))
class TestApplication { ...
```

**NB:** All mysql entities have to extend `JpaRepository` and mongo enities have to extend `MongoRepository`.

The datasource configs are straight forward as presented by spring documentation:

```
//mysql db config
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tangio
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test

#mongodb config
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=tangio
spring.data.mongodb.username=tangio
spring.data.mongodb.password=tangio
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

Comment: It works for your case because you have two db of different types. But if dbs are of the same type, you can't use that trick :-s

Answer (score 0):

once you start work with jpa and some driver is in your class path spring boot right away puts it inside as your data source (e.g h2 )
for using the defult data source therefore u will need only to define

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
```

if we go one step farther and u want to use two 
    I would reccomend to use two data sources such as explained here : 
    [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

Answer (score 0):

MySqlBDConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "PACKAGE OF YOUR CRUDS USING MYSQL DATABASE",entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEmFactory" ,transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager")
public class MySqlBDConfig{

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean(name="mysqlProperities")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mysql")
public DataSourceProperties mysqlProperities(){
    return new  DataSourceProperties();
}


@Bean(name="mysqlDataSource")
public DataSource interfaceDS(@Qualifier("mysqlProperities")DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties){
    return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();

}

@Primary
@Bean(name="mysqlEmFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEmFactory(@Qualifier("mysqlDataSource")DataSource mysqlDataSource,EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
    return builder.dataSource(mysqlDataSource).packages("PACKAGE OF YOUR MODELS").build();
}


@Bean(name="mysqlTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("mysqlEmFactory")EntityManagerFactory factory){
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}
}
```

H2DBConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "PACKAGE OF YOUR CRUDS USING MYSQL DATABASE",entityManagerFactoryRef = "dsEmFactory" ,transactionManagerRef = "dsTransactionManager")
public class H2DBConfig{

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean(name="dsProperities")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.h2")
        public DataSourceProperties dsProperities(){
            return new  DataSourceProperties();
        }


    @Bean(name="dsDataSource")
    public DataSource dsDataSource(@Qualifier("dsProperities")DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties){
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();

    }

    @Bean(name="dsEmFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dsEmFactory(@Qualifier("dsDataSource")DataSource dsDataSource,EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em =  builder.dataSource(dsDataSource).packages("PACKAGE OF YOUR MODELS").build();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter ven = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(ven);
        HashMap<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<>();
        prop.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(prop);
        em.afterPropertiesSet();
        return em;
    }


    @Bean(name="dsTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dsTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dsEmFactory")EntityManagerFactory factory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
#---mysql DATASOURCE---
spring.mysql.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.mysql.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
spring.mysql.username = root
spring.mysql.password = root
#----------------------

#---H2 DATASOURCE----
spring.h2.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.url = jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.h2.username = root
spring.h2.password = root
#---------------------------

#------JPA----- 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        ApplicationContext ac=SpringApplication.run(KeopsSageInvoiceApplication.class, args);
        UserMysqlDao userRepository = ac.getBean(UserMysqlDao.class)
        //for exemple save a new user using your repository 
        userRepository.save(new UserMysql());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated solution for MongoDB type No-SQL databases.

```java
package com.eg.config;

import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.eg.model","com.example.eg.repo"},
        mongoTemplateRef = "egMongoTemplate")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class EgMongoDBConfig {

    @Value("${connect-timeout}")
    private Integer connectTimeout;

    @Value("${local-threshold}")
    private Integer localThreshold;

    @Value("${ssl-enabled}")
    private Boolean sslEnabled;

    @Value("${ssl-invalid-host-name-allowed}")
    private Boolean sslInvalidHostNameAllowed;

    @Value("${max-wait-time}")
    private Integer maxWaitTime;

    @Value("${max-connection-idle-time}")
    private Integer maxConnectionIdleTime;

    @Value("${max-connection-life-time}")
    private Integer maxConnectionLifeTime;

    @Value("${server-selection-timeout}")
    private Integer serverSelectionTimeout;

    @Value("${min-heartbeat-frequency}")
    private Integer minHeartbeatFrequency;

    @Value("${heartbeat-frequency}")
    private Integer heartbeatFrequency;

    @Bean(name = "egProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongo.eg")
    public MongoProperties egProperties(){
        return new MongoProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "egMongoClient")
    public MongoClient mongoClient(@Qualifier("egProperties") MongoProperties mongoProperties){
        List<ServerAddress> serverAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] addressList = mongoProperties.getHost().split(",");
        for (String address: addressList){
            String[] hostAndPort = address.split(":");
            String host = hostAndPort[0];
            int port = Integer.parseInt(hostAndPort[1]);
            ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(host,port);
            serverAddresses.add(serverAddress);
        }

        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoProperties.getUsername(),
                        mongoProperties.getAuthenticationDatabase(),
                        mongoProperties.getPassword());

        return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> builder
                        .hosts(serverAddresses)
                        .requiredReplicaSetName(mongoProperties.getReplicaSetName())
                        .localThreshold(localThreshold, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .serverSelectionTimeout(serverSelectionTimeout,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> builder
                        .connectTimeout(connectTimeout,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder
                        .enabled(sslEnabled)
                        .invalidHostNameAllowed(sslInvalidHostNameAllowed))
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder -> builder
                        .maxConnectionIdleTime(maxConnectionIdleTime,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .maxConnectionLifeTime(maxConnectionLifeTime,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .maxWaitTime(maxWaitTime,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .applyToServerSettings(builder -> builder
                        .minHeartbeatFrequency(minHeartbeatFrequency,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .heartbeatFrequency(heartbeatFrequency,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .credential(credential)
                .build());
    }

    @Bean(name = "egMongoDBFactory")
    public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory(
            @Qualifier("egMongoClient") MongoClient mongoClient,
            @Qualifier("egProperties") MongoProperties mongoProperties){
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoClient,mongoProperties.getDatabase());
    }

    @Bean(name = "egMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Qualifier("egMongoDBFactory") MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory){
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDatabaseFactory);
    }

}
```

Added a sample `application.properties` for reference

```
connect-timeout=10000
local-threshold=15
ssl-enabled=false
ssl-invalid-host-name-allowed=false
max-wait-time=120000
max-connection-idle-time=0
max-connection-life-time=0
server-selection-timeout=30000
min-heartbeat-frequency=500
heartbeat-frequency=10000

mongodb.eg.replica-set=rd0
mongodb.eg.host=egw1634.bs.com:57054,egw1635.bs.com:57054,egw1636.bs.com:57054
mongodb.eg.port=57054
mongodb.eg.database=EG_DEV
mongodb.eg.username=admin
mongodb.eg.password=password
mongodb.eg.authentication-database=admin
```

You can add multiple databases as required with the above template.