# Data source inject to Crud Repository spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, repository, spring-data

Is there any way to inject or set up data source to Crud Repository?
I need one repository and multiple database with same schema.
I tried to make hash map with database name and data source and use something like that https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/ but it doesn't work

Comment: Refer link : [Spring-boot multiple datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614301/spring-boot-multiple-datasource) and [Use multiple database with spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring) these questions solve your problem.

Comment: No, they aren't because I need exactly one repository and one DAO. I just figured out how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you provide the solution as an answer (you can accept you own answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
@Component
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseMap databaseMap;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setTargetDataSources(databaseMap.getSourcesMap());
        setDefaultTargetDataSource(databaseMap.getSourcesMap().get("DEFAULT"));
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DatabaseContextHolder.getDatabaseType();
    }

}

@Configuration
public class DatabaseLoader {
    @Bean
    public DatabaseMap databaseMap() {
    //init databases using DataSourceBuilder
    return databaseMap;
    }
}
```

I change context same way as here https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: Can you please put the code inside databaseMap function from DatabaseLoader?