# AbstractRoutingDataSource strange behaviour

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

I am newbie in Spring. 
I use AbstractRoutingDataSource to change db connection in runtime and SpringBoot
My code is similar to this https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing but beans are configured programatically.

```
public class DatabaseContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new   ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static void setDatabaseType(String string) {
        contextHolder.set(string);
    }

    public static String getDatabaseType() {
        return (String) contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDatabaseType() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I change context like that (pseudocode):

```
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    private MyCrudRepository repository;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override run(){
         DatabaseContext.changeContext("db1");
         repository.findAll();          //data from db1 like expected
         DatabaseContext.changeContext("db2");
         repository.findAll();          //data from db2 like expected
    }
}
```

but when I change context in servlet class (pseudocode)

```
@Controller
public class MyWebController{
    @RequestMapping(someMapping)
    HttpEntity someMethod(){
         DatabaseContext.changeContext("db1");
         repository.findAll();          //data from db1 like expected
         DatabaseContext.changeContext("db2");
         repository.findAll();          //data from db1
    }

}
```

Context change just one time and I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: How does your `DatabaseContext` class looks like?

Comment: Thats my DatabaseContext http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400162/data-source-inject-to-crud-repository-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment54736148_33400162

Comment: No. Please add all related code to your so question. Nobody wants to collect all information from various so posts. Thanks.