# Multiple Databases in Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, netbeans-8

I want to ask how i connect second database in my program . First i tell you this is a inventry system . I want to get functionality that when i update the record in existing data base record also update into other databases. please checkout the code . I use this code for single database connection and for the update record . 
I create another button in my webpage . i need that when i click the second button record save in second database .

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
jdbc.driver2=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bvasdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username=admin
jdbc.password=admin
```

---

```
<beans:property name="dataSource">
<beans:bean class="${jdbc.driver}">
  <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" /> 
  <beans:property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" /> 
  <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" /> 
  </beans:bean>
```

```
@RequestMapping("partmaintenanceupdate")
    public ModelAndView partmaintenanceUpdate(@RequestParam("partmaintenancemode") String partmaintenancemode,
            @RequestParam("searchpartno") String searchpartno,
            @RequestParam("makemodelcodeselected") String makemodelcodeselected,
            @RequestParam("subcategoryselected") String subcategoryselected,
            @RequestParam("ordertypeselected") String ordertypeselected, Model map, HttpSession session,
            ModelAndView mav) {
        AppUser user = (AppUser) session.getAttribute("user");
        if (user == null) {
            throw new OrderNotFoundException();
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("#partmaintenanceupdate");
            if (subcategorylistdd.size() == 0) {
                subcategorylistdd = mainService.getAllSubCategory();
            }
            if (makemodellistdd.size() == 0) {
                makemodellistdd = mainService.getAllMakeModelMap();
            }
            if (ordertypelistdd.size() == 0) {
                ordertypelistdd = mainService.getAllOrderType();
            }

            partmaintenancemode = "update";

            parts.setPartno(request.getParameter("partno").trim().toUpperCase());
            parts.setInterchangeno(request.getParameter("interchangeno").trim().toUpperCase());
            parts.setYear(request.getParameter("year").trim());
            parts.setYearfrom(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("yearfrom").trim()));
            parts.setYearto(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("yearto").trim()));
            parts.setPartdescription(request.getParameter("partdescription").trim());
            parts.setActualprice(new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("actualprice").trim()));
            parts.setCostprice(new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("costprice").trim()));
            parts.setListprice(new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("listprice").trim()));
            parts.setWholesaleprice(new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("wholesaleprice").trim()));
            parts.setUnitsinstock(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("unitsinstock").trim()));
            parts.setUnitsonorder(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("unitsonorder").trim()));
            parts.setReorderlevel(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("reorderlevel").trim()));
            parts.setSafetyquantity(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("safetyquantity").trim()));
            parts.setKeystonenumber(request.getParameter("keystonenumber").trim());
            parts.setOemnumber(request.getParameter("oemnumber").trim());
            parts.setDpinumber(request.getParameter("dpinumber").trim());
            parts.setLocation(request.getParameter("location").trim());
            parts.setCapa(request.getParameter("capa").trim());
            parts.setMakemodelcode(makemodellistdd.get(request.getParameter("makemodelcodeselected").trim()));
            parts.setSubcategory(subcategorylistdd.get(request.getParameter("subcategoryselected").trim()));
            parts.setOrdertype(request.getParameter("ordertypeselected").trim());
            partsService.updatePartsMaintenance(parts);

            mav.clear();
            mav.setViewName("partmaintenancepage");
            mav.addObject("user", user);
            mav.addObject("branch", branch);
            mav.addObject("appcss", appcss);
            mav.addObject("sysdate", InsightUtils.getNewUSDate());
            mav.addObject("partmaintenancemode", partmaintenancemode);
            mav.addObject("subcategorylistdd", subcategorylistdd);
            mav.addObject("makemodellistdd", makemodellistdd);
            mav.addObject("ordertypelistdd", ordertypelistdd);
            mav.addObject("makemodelcodeselected", makemodelcodeselected);
            mav.addObject("subcategoryselected", subcategoryselected);
            mav.addObject("ordertypeselected", ordertypeselected);
            mav.addObject("searchpartno", searchpartno);
            mav.addObject("parts", parts);
            return mav;
        }
    }
```

---

```
@Transactional
    public void updatePartsMaintenance(Parts parts) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(parts);

        // updateSubcategoryOnParts();
        // updateMakemodelOnParts();
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
```

I create a button in my webpage . i need to update the data in second database only when i click the button .

Comment: Check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614301/spring-boot-multiple-datasource

Comment: This thread may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

If you need more then one DB you need more then one HibernateSessionFactory.

You just create an hibernate factory for each DB with the relevant table mapping in each configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Create Multiple Datasource beans and use `@Qualifier` while autowiring to select your desired connection.

Comment: How i update second database at the same time when updating first . ?

Comment: If that is the case than you have to create  2 connection.