# Multiple data source configuration

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

How can I add more data source into my generated project? It mean I want to use more than one data source in my project? It would be great if someone give me a sample which solve this problem. I am new with jhipster.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Nothing specific to JHipster, check the spring boot docs and this has been covered here also many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Multiple Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614301/spring-boot-multiple-datasource)

Comment: You'r right. Its my mistake.