# Spring Boot integration test using multiple database types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

In my test I need test with different databases (mysql, oracle, etc.) and I would like to know if it's possible with SpringRunner.

I'm using @SqlGroup and @Sql annotations, but I didn't discover how to indicate script files (sql) corresponding database.

Example:

```
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:tenantBeforeTestRun.sql")
```

This annotation configures my test to execute the script to all database types, but this file didn't work on Oracle.

Comment: You probably need to provide your configuration and Spring boot application to be able to know what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Sql` annotation lets you define a `SqlConfig` which contains a `datasource` bean name. 
Then you can define many datasource beans, with possibly different drivers and refer them from different @Sql. This might be helpful: [Spring Boot Multiple Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614301/spring-boot-multiple-datasource)

```
@Sql(..., config = @SqlConfig(datasource = "db1", ...)
```

application.properties:

```
#first db
spring.db1.url = [url]
spring.db1.username = [username]
spring.db1.password = [password]
spring.db1.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#second db ...
spring.secondDatasource.url = [url]
spring.secondDatasource.username = [username]
spring.secondDatasource.password = [password]
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Then, somewhere in `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean(name = "db1")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.db1")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```