# How to switch database source repository during running application in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

The requirement is - In my application, having more than 5 databases, those are source and target databases.  through UI page, User have to choose source database and target database and based on this data we have to fetch records from one database and store to target database (both having same tables).. 
In spring boot, is it possible to switch databases? if not then should i go with JDBC Programing?

Comment: Ye its possible to have multiple datasources. Feel free to google it out, couple answers can be found on SO as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Multiple Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614301/spring-boot-multiple-datasource)